# Download using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a UIImageView that is displaying an image using a URL, I have a download button that brings up a UIActionSheet which will then download the file using the URL i want to know how to do the coding for the download part of it using NSURLConnection.

```
- (IBAction)DownloadClick:(id)sender {

    UIActionSheet *Action = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                         initWithTitle:@"Options" 
                         delegate:self 
                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                         destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                         otherButtonTitles:@"Download", nil];

    [Action showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {  //The Download code will go here This is where i need ur help


          }
```

The Url is saved in a string named "Url".

Comment: What download code have you tried?

Comment: I tried the ASIHTTPRequest method but i had a lot of issues in importing the classes from the github project file

Comment: Google 'AFNetworking' or 'NSURLConnection example'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you tried Google for this. Anyway, here is your code and don't forget to add *NSURLConnectionDataDelegate*,

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0) {  //The Download code will go here This is where i need ur help

    //-------------------------------------------------------
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your_data_url"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                         timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connection) {
        NSLog(@"succeed...");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed...");
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

}
```

Comment: It shows succeed but i have to show the file being downloaded how do i do that?

Comment: i have to save it in the gallery folder of the phone how do i do that?

Comment: To save image write code in didReceiveData and whether it is finished or not can be checked in connectionDidFinishLoading method. It will fire after finishing download.

Comment: It is not downloading it is just checking whether the connection has been made or not

Comment: your image is in data object of didReceiveData method. convert it to image and save it.

Comment: Hi, I tried to find a way to convert the data object in didReceiiveData method to an image and then save it on a specific file path but i couldnt find anything useful could you help

Comment: in didReceiveData to convert data into image write: UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; and to save image as data write: NSString *dirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/img.png",dirPath];
 [data writeToFile:dataFilePath atomically:YES];

Answer (score 1):

Make use of asynchronous request for image download. It can  also help you identify errors, if any during image downloading.

```
 NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://imageAddress.com"];
 NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
    NSData * data,
    NSError * error) {
if (!error){
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
           // do whatever you want with image
           }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need synchronous download you can try this code:

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://site.com/imageName.ext"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Now you have an image that you can use.

If you need an asynchronous request I suggest you to read the [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html), that helps you handle the download of the file.